# Hash default value is a hash with same default value

Tags: ruby, hash, default-value

Setting a default value of a hash like this:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hsh, key| hsh[key] = {} }
```

will create (and assign) a new hash for an unknown key, but will return `nil` for an unknown key of the created hash:

```
hash[:unkown_key] #=> {}
hash[:unkown_key][:nested_unknown] #=> nil
```

I could make it work for the second level like this:

```
hash = Hash.new do |hsh, key|
  hsh[key] = Hash.new { |nest_hsh, nest_key| nest_hsh[nest_key] = {} }
end
```

but, it does not work at the third level:

```
hash[:unkown_key][:nested_unknown] #=> {}
hash[:unkown_key][:nested_unknown][:third_level] #=> nil
```

How can I make it work at arbitrary levels?

```
hash[:unkown_key][:nested_unknown][:third_level][...][:nth_level] #=> {}
```

Comment: An arbitrarily large number (which you seem to intend) is not infinity (in fact, infinity is not even a number in the ordinary sense, unless you are talking about non-standard analysis in the sense of Abraham Robinson). You seem to be confusing them (I see too many users on this site who are confusing them).

Comment: Don't take my `infinity` too literal - of course this is only an exaggeration to underline my question. Didn't want to make a mathematician think to hard about this, I'm sorry if I did.

Comment: Oh and, btw, `:infinity` is a symbol, not a number ;-)

Comment: Didn't you intend to write that there are infinite many levels (which actually goes against your real intention)?

Comment: @Markus I've replaced `:infinity` with `:nth_level`, hope this is clearer.

Comment: I wanted to say the hash is really deeply nested, using `infinity` as an exaggeration. I think literal infinity many levels are not possible anyway (would consume a lot of memory I think - infinity amount of memory? ;-)). Thank God @Stefan cleared it up for us ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of mind bending, but you can pass the hash's [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) to the inner hash:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

hash[:foo] #=> {}
hash[:foo][:bar] #=> {}
hash[:foo][:bar][:baz] #=> {}

hash #=> {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>{}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the cleanest solution to me!

Answer (score 3):

```
bottomless_hash = ->() do
  Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = bottomless_hash.call }
end

hash = bottomless_hash.call
hash[:unkown_key][:nested_unknown][:third_level][:fourth] # => {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create `method` that will do this with Recursion

```
class Hash
  def self.recursive
    new { |hash, key| hash[key] = recursive }
  end
end

hash = Hash.recursive
hash[:unknown_key] # => {}
hash[:first_unknown_key][:second_unknown_key][...][:infinity]
# hash => {first_unknown_key:  {second_unknown_key: {... {infinity: {}}}}}
```